# how to passing value codebehind C# to javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net

Any one can help me..I want to pass the C# value to javascript..I only get pass 2 values only to the javascript..I dont know how to pass a tbSTime,tbETime and tbIndo2..Please help me..Thank You

**This is code behind:**

```
        {
           // get the meeting info based on the id
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request["id"]);
            MeetingClass.MeetingInfo m = MeetingClass.MeetingInfo.GetInfo(id);
            // fill data
            tbtitle2.Value = m.Title;
            tbdate2.Value = m.Date.ToShortDateString();
            tbSTime.Value = m.StartTime.ToShortTimeString();
            tbETime.Value = m.EndTime.ToShortTimeString();
            tbIndo2.Value = m.Desc; 
        }
```

**And this is javascript:**

```
function getInfo() {

    $('#<%=tbtitle.ClientID%>').val($('#<%=tbtitle2.ClientID%>').val());
    $('#<%=tbdate.ClientID%>').val($('#<%=tbdate2.ClientID%>').val());
}
```

Comment: Is the javascript in the same file as the codebehind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell on your code, you are setting an asp:HiddenField (since you are using .Value) and then using that to populate your asp:TextBox w/ jQuery.  If that is the case, then you need to do something like this.

```
$('#<%=aspTextBoxName1.ClientID%>').val($('#<%=tbSTime.ClientID%>').val());
$('#<%=aspTextBoxName2.ClientID%>').val($('#<%=tbETime.ClientID%>').val());
$('#<%=aspTextBoxName3.ClientID%>').val($('#<%=tbIndo2.ClientID%>').val());
```

Where aspTextBoxName1, aspTextBoxName2, aspTextBoxName3 are the names of your new textboxes.

I don't know if you really need those hidden form fields, there are easier ways to do this if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

in controller:

```
ViewBag.tbSTime = tbSTime;
```

in view:

```
$('#<%=tbtitle.ClientID%>').val("<%= ViewBag.tbSTime %>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Iam sorry but iam not sure what exactly you need, but from what i understood i can provide you with this:
If You want to send some value from Server side variables to Javascript function one way you can do this as follows,

```
function abc(x,y)
{
//Do you things here
}
```

and from server side call javascript code as follows

```
string a=textbox1.text;    
string b=textbox2.text;    
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "displayalertmessage", "abc("+a+","+b+");", true);
```